# How to set the selected index of a dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

How can I set the selected value of a dropdown using javascript?

This is my HTML:

```
<select id="strPlan" name="strPlan" class="formInput">
    <option value="0">Select a Plan</option>
</select>
```

I am using javascript to add values. Can anyone tell me how to call a function to select a value?

Comment: Post your javascript. We can't guess at what exactly you are doing.

Comment: What you have tried.Port your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I set the selected value of a dropdown using javascript?

So, you want to change the value of the option that is currently selected. Is that correct?

```
function setValueOfSelected(select, valueToSetTo){
    select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = valueToSetTo;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
setValueOfSelected(document.getElementById('strPlan'), 'selected');
```

[Demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/bh5x7y54z.html)

---

**In case you meant that you want to select an option based on its value, use this:**

Declare this function:

```
function setOptionByValue(select, value){
    var options = select.options;
    for(var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++){
        if(options[i].value === value){
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            return true; //Return so it breaks the loop and also lets you know if the function found an option by that value
        }
    }
    return false; //Just to let you know it didn't find any option with that value.
}
```

Now call that to set the option by value, like this, with the first parameter being the select element and the second being the value:

```
setOptionByValue(document.getElementById('strPlan'), '1');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8Pfa/)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work, I believe:

```
function setDropDownList(elementRef, valueToSetTo)
{
    var isFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < elementRef.options.length; i++) {
        if (elementRef.options[i].value == valueToSetTo) {
            elementRef.options[i].selected = true;
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if ( isFound == false )
        elementRef.options[0].selected = true;
}
```

Found it [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1311602.aspx/1). Just Google for something like 'set selected value dropdown javascript' and you'll get many possible solutions.